# sudo iwlist wlan0 scan not work

Tags: networking, wifi

## Background

I connected MacBook Pro with Raspberrypi3 B+ by Lan and SSH because I have no keyboard and monitor for PI3.

```
ssh pi@192.168.2.3
```

OS : raspbian-stretch-lite

Model : Raspberry Pi3 B+

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

## Problem

There are many Access Points but `No scan results`

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

wlan0     No scan results
```

What should I do?

Comment: "What should I do?" start by providing some information - what are your network settings? what networks are available?

Comment: what networks are available ? => what do you mean? I think every networks are available. For example, my macbook can scan and find many networks(wifi ssids)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my Raspberrypi.
I buy a new Rasberrypi3 B+, then now it works well!!